# While merging, how to tell Magit to use one version of the file?

Tags: spacemacs, magit, git, ediff

When I merge something and there are conflicts, I can go to the file in the magit status page (`SPC-g-s`) and press, for example, `e` to start `ediff`. Within that, I can scroll through all conflicts and press either `a` or `b` to tell it, which version to use (my local version or the external version). How can I do that for all conflicts at once? Sometimes, I don't want to go through all conflicts because sometimes I know that all of them should resolve the same way. I can't find out how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These versions are also called "stages" and the command to pick on is `magit-checkout-stage`. You can invoke that using <kbd>M-x</kbd> of course, but you can also just press <kbd>k</kbd> (`magit-discard`) on the conflicting file to discard the other stages. (But be aware that this prompts you for which side to *keep*, not which side to *discard*.)